# Forcing data seeding during release stage of the pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I am having trouble seeding data into thre database using devops. I have a YAML with the following build step (I've stripped out irrelevant steps):

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0
      dotnet tool restore
      dotnet ef migrations script -p $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(My.SQLProject)/$(My.SQLProject).csproj -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/migrations/script.sql -i

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

This creates a migration SQL script just fine and pops it into drop.

During release I create the database using an ARM deployment task I then run the SQL script:

```
      - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'my-sub'
          ServerName: 'my-server.database.windows.net'
          DatabaseName: 'my-db'
          SqlUsername: 'my-sqluser'
          SqlPassword: 'my-password'
          deployType: SqlTask
          SqlFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/migrations/script.sql'
```

This works fine - the schema in the DB is created.

I then create the App Service with connection string and the App Service connects to the DB just fine.

The bit I can't seem to get to work is the data seeding. I've googled lots and there are plenty of articles that talk about creating migrations and creating SQL scripts and then running the script in Devops. And there are plenty that talk about seeding data outside of Devops, but the bit I'm struggling with is how to get it to seed the data in Devops. One odd thing I have noticed is that if I re-run the build / deploy YAML, it then seeds the data without me having to tell it. So, I guess there are two questions:

1. Is data seeding something that MUST (or SHOULD) be done in the App Service code during App Service Startup, or is it something that should be instigated during the release pipeline in Devops? (I'm not the App Service developer. The Dev says he thinks it should be happening at App Startup. It doesn't so my thinking is that if he's missing something in his code, perhaps I can say "don't worry, I can kick off the data seeding myself in Devops".
2. If it should be done in Devops, *how* should it be done? I would have thought that "dotnet ef database update -p " ought to do it, but that doesn't seem to work in the release pipeline.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I have an answer. It's not pretty but it works. I don't know why the dev's seeding isn't working, but I can force it in Devops like this:

- Deploy the App Service (AzureWebApp@1)
- Add the Connection Strings (AzureAppServiceSettings@1)
- Re-deploy the App Service (AzureWebApp@1)

That seems to "force" the seeding. Job done.